# How can I stop my parallax overlay from interfering with my form and link fields?

Tags: html, css, parallax

I have implemented simple parallax images into my index page of my PHP site. For some reason the login form is misbehaving as a result of the parallax header I have implemented. On that photo there is an image overlay placed by a div which I have named logo. I can be sure it is the culprit because when I comment it out the the form fields and links work. The site is at http://www.mattmacy.com/greenia/ . Please see that the form fields are not working. I have included my css for my 3 images and the logo class. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>FORUM</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body style="background-color: maroon";>
<div style= "background-color: gold; border-style: solid;">

//This "logo" div stops my form and link fields from working  
<div class="pimg1">
<div class="logo"></div>
</div>

<div style="background-color: gold; border-style: solid;">
<h1>Matt Macy's Forum</h1>

<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
echo "<form action='login_parse.php' method='post'>
Username: <input type='text' name='username' />&nbsp;
Password: <input type='password' name='password' />&nbsp;
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Log In'/></form>";
echo "You can joing this site with Admin approval <a 
href='register.php' class='Links'>Register</a>";
}else {
    echo "You are logged in as ". $_SESSION['username']. "with a level 
of " . $_SESSION['level']."<a href='logout_parse.php' 
class='Links'>Logout</a>";
}   if (isset($_SESSION['level']) && ($_SESSION['level'] == 'Admin')){
        echo "<a href='authenticate.php' 
class='authenticate'>Authenticate</a>";
        echo "<a href='postAudiowithPayPal.php' 
class='postAudiowithPayPal'>Post audio with PayPal</a>";

}
echo"</div><br>";
//This is my second parallax image that doesn't cause difficulty
echo"<div class='pimg2'><span class='border'></span></div>";
```

This is from my style.css file. I am not sure if I will need to style my Links class which I have designated for my links.

```
.pimg1{
background-image:url('pimg1.jpg');
min-height:100%;
height:600px;
}

.pimg2{
background-image:url('pimg2.jpg');
min-height:100%;
height:500px;
}
.pimg3{
background-image:url('pimg3.jpg');
min-height:100%;
height:500px;
}

@media(max-width:568px){
.pimg1, .pimg2, .pimg3{
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
}

.logo{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-image:url('SpiritualAutomaton2.png');
position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
top:50%;
margin-top:-50px;
margin-left:130px;


}
.Links{
      ?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `.logo` height. Try using the same size as the image you are using as the background. You can see in this image and by placing your mouse over the left-most input and moving to the right that the logo div is blocking the elements below. Another option is to set `pointer-events:none;` on the `.logo` element but that's a bit hacky in this case.

[image]

Comment: I changed height to match the image: height: 1667px; and I still am experiencing problems with those fields.

Comment: That logo image is 173px tall, not 1667px. You have `height: 100%;` set on `.logo` - change that to `height: 173px;`

Comment: Oh you meant pixels of logo. I thought you meant background thanks